# How can I get the logined in user details in django 2 models?

Tags: django, authentication

FYI, I am still in a very beginning stage of Django.

I have created a model for task scheduling. The model is registered in *admin.py*. The Tasks will be assigned manually to some assignee from the main list of operators (users).
Now I would like to track the change of the task form in the Django admin. I managed to track the time of change but I would like to get the login and the user first and last names and assign them to this method below instead of the `assignee.first_name` & `assignee.last_name`

```
def __str__(self):
            return "%s last edit at %s by %s  %s" % (self.title, datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), self.assignee.first_name, self.assignee.last_name,)
```

Here is my model:

```
class Operator(User):
    # full_name=User.get_full_name
    class Meta:
            ordering = ('first_name', )
            proxy = True

class Task( models.Model):
    # assignee = User.first_name + ' ' + User.last_name 
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(User,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=True,
        related_name="assigned_tasks",
        related_query_name="assigned_task",
    )
    creation_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s last edit at %s by %s  %s" % (self.title, datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), self.assignee.first_name, self.assignee.last_name,)
```

Comment: If you want to keep track of the time of the last edit and of the user who made the last edit, you need to add those fields to the model itself, e.g. `updated_by = ForeignKey(User, related_name='updated_tasks')` and modify your admin view to store the logged in user there. The `__str__()` method is just python's method to "print" the object, so it doesn't store anything.

Comment: thanks for your comment- this has created a new drop list in the Django admin, which is not what I need. I would like to store the fist name and last name of who made the last edit.

Comment: exclude that field from the list of fields shown in django admin. but you want to "store" it, so you need to add it as a field to the model.

Comment: done that! now How can I know the last editor names? sorry about keep bothering

Comment: override `save_model()`, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model), the example shown is actually exactly what you need.